# React Native Catch in Fetch API method does not work

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I'm trying to get some data from an API and display on my app. So in order to handle errors and get data, I used below code.

```
async componentDidMount() {
let data =  await fetch('https://demo61235421.mockable.io/getDfo')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  this.setState({
    totOrder : responseJson.totalOrders,
  })
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error('error')
});
return data;
}
```

But when I get an error response from the API, this code does not show an error on Simulator screen. I don't know why but screen stays the same.

This is my JSON response,

```
{
   "error": "Error 445"
}
```

**Problem**

1. Why this does not catch the error? What am I missing?
2. As I know, since JSON response contain ID called 'error' this should
   be working. Am I correct?

**UPDATE**

After changing the code to following, Still error does not being showed.

```
async componentDidMount()
{
  try
  {
    let data =  await fetch('https://demo64533421.mockable.io/getDfo');
    let responseJson = await data.json();
    this.setState({
      Data : true,
      totOrder : responseJson.totalOrders,
    })
  }
  catch(error) 
  {
    console.error(error)
  }

}
```

Also, response status has been set to `500 (Inernal Server Error)` code.

Comment: I wonder if the issue you are observing is related to React Native. Specifically, `console.error` displays the big red warning in the UI, which makes the app look like it had crashed. It did `catch` the error. Try, instead, to `console.log` or `console.debug`, which should display the error on the developer console, leaving the view intact.

Answer (score 0):

You are using async/await. You don't need 'then' and 'catch'. The purpose of using callback functions (then/catch) is for asynchronous behavior where 'fetch' would be asynchronous. However, when you say 'await' it is waiting to get the result back from the fetch.

You should do it like this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
   try {
      let data =  await fetch('https://demo61235421.mockable.io/getDfo')
      // Do success scenarios here.
   }catch(err){
      // Perform error handling here
   }
}
```

Comment: What is returned in data?

Answer (score 0):

For the fetch API, the status returned by the server matters also, from my experience, if it's not the HTTP based error status codes (e.g. 404, 500) then an error might not be thrown.